# Catching BACK key event not working while in Edit Mode (TextField = Libgdx)

Tags: android-layout, libgdx, scene2d

I'm trying to call a method right after the BACK key is pressed. I'm trying to do this while in edit mode (when writing text to a TextField using Scene2D , libgdx), so the keyboard buttons will be present when I do this. Using a simple InputProcessor set to the Stage, or even an InputMultiplexer, it seems it's not working either way. The system somehow catches the event and returns false after the system keyboard disappears from the screen.

First method used:

```
@Override
public void create() {
     ...
     Gdx.input.setCatchBackKey(true);
     ...
}

@Override
public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
     ...
     if(keycode == Keys.BACK){
        // Optional back button handling (e.g. ask for confirmation)
        ...
        if (shouldReallyQuit)
          Gdx.app.exit();
     }
     return false;
}
```

Second method used:

```
InputProcessor backProcessor = new InputAdapter() {
    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {

        if ((keycode == Keys.ESCAPE) || (keycode == Keys.BACK))

            // Some code

        return false;
    }
};
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(mStage,
        backProcessor);
Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(multiplexer);
```

What could be the issue here?

Also, the TextField textbox doesn't have a setOnEditorActionListener method used to solve the above issues.

Comment: hey, did you fix it somehow? to catch the back button while the keyboard is visible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it might be the most stupid bag I ever had but I fixed it. U just need to switch between the stage and the back processor in InputMultyplexer() like this:
InputMultiplexer multiplexer = new InputMultiplexer(backProcessor, mStage);

It seems like that way it gives backProcessor priority over mStage.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like: 
adding listener to your textField as following, which catch enter key and then hide keyboard an lost focus. After this, you can catch BACK key as normal.

```
    textField.setTextFieldListener(new TextField.TextFieldListener() {
    public void keyTyped(TextField textField, char key) {
    if (key == '\n' || key == '\r') {
     textField.getOnscreenKeyboard().show(false);
     getStage().setKeyboardFocus(null);
    }   
   }
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private EventListener textListener = new EventListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean handle(Event event) {
            if (event instanceof InputEvent) {
                if (((InputEvent) event).getType() == InputEvent.Type.keyDown && ((InputEvent) event).getKeyCode() == Input.Keys.BACK) {
                    ((TextField)event.getListenerActor()).getOnscreenKeyboard().show(false);
                    stage.setKeyboardFocus(null);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

adding listener worked for me. Accepted answer by amit did not work in my case.